WPF. MVVM cross использование плагина MvvmCross.Plugin.Color
подскажите пожалуйста как использовать MvvmCross.Plugin.Color для WPF проекта с использованием фреймворка MVVM cross.
В документации сказано использовать The Mvx Color ValueConverters для
Windows 
  Fill="{Binding CurrentColor, Converter={StaticResource NativeColor}}"


где CurrentColor свойство типа System.Drawing.Color

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/color
Код регистрации плагина в DI.
namespace MvvmCross.Plugin.Color
{
    public abstract class BasePlugin : IMvxPlugin
    {
        public virtual void Load(IMvxIoCProvider provider)
        {
            if (provider.TryResolve<IMvxValueConverterRegistry>(out var registry) && registry != null)
            {
                registry.AddOrOverwrite("ARGB", new MvxARGBValueConverter());
                registry.AddOrOverwrite("NativeColor", new MvxNativeColorValueConverter());
                registry.AddOrOverwrite("RGBA", new MvxRGBAValueConverter());
                registry.AddOrOverwrite("RGB", new MvxRGBValueConverter());
                registry.AddOrOverwrite("RGBIntColor", new MvxRGBIntColorValueConverter());
            }
        }
    }
}

Я наследуюсь от класса BasePlugin - MyColorPlugin и выполняю загрузку плагина
    var pluginManager = Mvx.IoCProvider!.Resolve<IMvxPluginManager>();
    pluginManager!.EnsurePluginLoaded<MyColorPlugin>();

А вот что делать дальше, как использовать во View конвертор?
Converter={StaticResource NativeColor}

Почему без явного объявления в ресурсах должен появится NativeColor?
